# Is it possible to set log4j pattern layout for imported library?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I was able to output an exported library's logs with our application's logs, but the problem is that they use a different pattern layout.
The library's logs are like this:

```
2020-08-07 16:54:44 INFO  logs content
```

Our application has this layout:

```
[2020-août-07 16:54:45 PM] [WARN ] [com.foo.class] log content
```

I did add the configuration file's location as a vm option, and I also did add these libraries:

```
log4j-api-2.11.2.jar
log4j-core-2.11.2.jar
log4j-1.2-api-2.11.2.jar
log4j2.xml
while excluding: 
    log4j-1.2.x.jar
```

to follow the [log4j FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#exclusions) but that wasn't enough.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

**edit :**
We use `log4j 2.11.2`, here is a snippet of the dependency tree :

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.26:compile
```

While the library normally uses: `log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15`, here is the snippet before its exclusion:

```
[INFO] |  |     +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
```

After the exculsion, I can see that in my dependency tree there is no log4j 1.2.15

**edit 2:**
Here is my log4j2.yaml:

```
    Configuration:
  status: WARN
  name: Default
  Properties:
    Property:
      - name: log-path
        value: logs
  Appenders:
    Console:
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: '[%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a}] [%t] [%-5level] [%logger{36}] %msg%n'
      name: Console
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
    RollingFile:
      name: File
      fileName: ${log-path}/lfile-name.log
      filePattern: ${log-path}/file-name-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
      PatternLayout:
        MarkerPatternSelector:
          defaultPattern: "[%d{yyyy-MMM-dd}] [%t] [%-5level] [%logger{36}] %msg%n"
  Loggers:
    Root:
      additivity: false
      level: INFO
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: Console
        - ref: File
    logger:
      - name: com.external.library
        additivity: false
        level: INFO
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: Console
          - ref: File
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. What is the library using for logging? What is your application using for logging? Ideally you need to route that into the framework you are using for logging. From what you are describing you haven't accomplished that and it is still using a separate logging configuration. You could modify the libraries configuration if you know where it is. Can you update your question to include that information and the relevant configuration files?

Comment: @rgoers thanks for responding, I did edit my question to add the information you requested. How can I make sure that the library's logging framework is redirected to mine? and do you know how i can check where the library is pulling its configuration from?

Comment: Can you provide your logging configuration as well as the configuration for log4j 1?

Comment: I don't have a configuration for log4j 1, only a configuration for log4j2 in yaml file. In this configuration I did add a section in Logger.logger for the external library. The question has been edited, Thanks again @rgoers